# Carousel header issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make carousel from top header's menu. I wrote styles but there's something unexpected: menu's links transformed into the column. When I added `display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;` in `.top_menu` it transformed back inline. But now I can only see the first link. How can I fix it or is there another ways to make carousel in top header?
Code itself:

```
<div class="top_header">


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 98%;" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="left" valign="bottom">
<a href="./"><img src="./images/logo_new.png" border="0" alt=""></a>
</td>
  <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 98%;" align="center">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" class="top_menu">
        <div class="top_menu_link_container">
          <div class="top_menu_link">
       <div class="top_menu_link_container">

@keyframes scroll {0% {transform: translate(0, 0)} 100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0)}}

.top_menu_link_container{
padding-left: 100%;
animation: scroll 15s infinite linear}

.top_menu {
width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;}
```

And Codepen if it helps https://codepen.io/sergeigyr/pen/qBZZRbX

Comment: Remove the `padding-left:100%` you have applied to the `.top_menu_link_container` class.

Comment: @MarkBurnsRed i did it but now links are layering on each other and its don't act like carousel